# How to define a query parameter with REST API?

Tags: rest-api, validation

I'm trying to define a GET REST API endpoint with **register_rest_route**

**register_rest_route** supports defining a URL parameter and it is documented at https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#arguments

I would love to define a list of query parameters and let Wordpress handle the validation part. Is there an official way to do so?

Comment: Yes, you linked to it. What do you need help with? You mention WordPress 'handling the validation', but it can't do that unless you tell it how, which is what the `validate_callback` is for.

Comment: @JacobPeattie The link explains about how to define an URL parameter (/author/(?P<id>\d+)). I would like to define a query parameter (ex: ?id=test)

Comment: They're defined the same way, in the `args` argument. By using regex in the endpoint you can accept them as part of the URL, but by default they're passed as query parameters.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Ah! I did not know that. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you post the answer as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, from the [link you posted](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#arguments) there are examples for both sanitising and validating the parameters. Validating does a check which can fail and block the API call from running; sanitising just does some operations to clean or interpret the parameter and does not stop the API call from running.

An example of validation, taken from the page:

```
<?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    'args' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
          return is_numeric( $param );
        }
      ),
    ),
  ) );
} );
```

You can see in the second parameter of `register_rest_route` that this defines an endpoints like `/author/1234`

The format of the second parameter of [register_rest_route](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) breaks down as:

- `/author/` initial part of the URL to match
- `?P` a code specific to this function that means 'parameter'. Note this is not included in the URL when called
- `<id>` optional name for the parameter, used belows in `args`, not included as part of URL.
- `\d+` the regex for this parameter